# specifying versions of library, using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github, cocoapods

This is basic issue but I'm so stuck with this.

I want to specify the version of releases of libraries(to get the latest one) but it doesn't work always.

For example, when I tried to specify the version of the library below, it failed again...

Please help me with this.

[image: This is the version I want to install.]

[image: This is how I specified]

[image: and this is how I failed..]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `pod repo update` then `pod install`

Comment: Hi, Ahmed. I wrote pod repo update like below the comment of  # Pods for YPImagePicker2 and hit the install button but it said that "[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method `update'"

Comment: Are you using terminal?

Comment: Nope, I'm using CocoaPods app on desktop(version 1.5.2)

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, I usually install libraries with terminal, I just had the same issue and solved it by navigating to the project directory and running pod repo update on terminal, then pod install.

Comment: 'update' and 'install' shouldn't be in your pod file.

Comment: You mean I shouldnt use the method "update" when I hit the install button? Maybe I shall try to install pods in terminal..

Comment: Did you add 'update' to your pod file? that's what causing the second error `"[!] Invalid Podfile file: undefined local variable or method `update'"`. Yes in your terminal try executing pod repo update then pod install

Comment: Thanks, but how can I execute pod repo update using terminal precisely? I did "pod init" in my project in terminal and created Podfile. then I wrote pod repo update or pod repo and did "pod install" but didnt work..

Comment: Sorry I think I got to make it done! I just get another error which says [!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down. Thanks so much for your help Ahmed

Comment: Is it giving you the same error? First, you change directory to your project directory cd /your-project-directory. Then pod repo update. Then pod install. If it stills gives you the same error try deleting Podfile.lock file and Pods folder then pod install.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, sorry for the delayed reply! Yes, I could fix the error by installing openSSL! It seems like Github decided to reject all the accesses which doesn't satisfy their new standard so I needed to get the better networking... Thank you so much for your help!